How did Scorpius find out that this character had become a Death Eater in Cursed Child
I've not seen the play(s), but I read the book version of Harry Potter and the Cursed Child and am a little confused. At the end of Act II, Scorpius returns to the present to find that his friend, Albus Potter, isn't with him (because history has changed). He almost immediately learns that Harry Potter is long-dead, because he tells Umbridge (now the Headmistress) that he is looking for Albus. But he clearly doesn't know anything about the bad future without hearing it from someone. There are a few scenes in which Scorpius speaks with Umbridge (again), Draco, and a few other students, and learns that he's big man on campus, and that mudbloods are hunted and killed, but no one is interested in answering his questions about anything else. Finally, Scorpius goes to the library to research and says to himself not "Now, what happened to Cedric?" but rather "Why did Cedric become a Death-Eater?" Is there something I missed in the stage-setting or dialogue that explains how Scorpius leapt to this, or should I assume that someone told him offstage that this nobody (Cedric being a nobody in this future) had become a Death-Eater, or that Scorpius had made a lucky guess?

It happened off-stage. It's referenced in Act Three, Scene I.
Apparently Scorpius has been asking around, trying to find out what happened to Harry and Cedric after the altered Tri-Wizard Tournament.

DOLORES UMBRIDGE: But in the three days since I found you in that lake on Voldemort Day, you’ve become . . . odder and odder. In particular, this sudden obsession with Harry Potter . . .
SCORPIUS: I don’t . . .
DOLORES UMBRIDGE: Questioning everyone you can about the Battle of Hogwarts. How Potter died. Why Potter died. And this ludicrous fascination with Cedric Diggory. Scorpius, we’ve checked you for hexes and curses — there were none we can see — so I’m asking if there’s anything I can do — to restore you to what you were . . .


Ah.  That does explain it.  The first thing they'd mention is that he was a Death-Eater (since the alternative is "He's a wanted criminal or dead").  Thanks.  Don't know how I missed that.
